# Laravel: Get not related items in a many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to get all items not related to the specific instance, in a many to many relation in Laravel?

Example:

I have two models, `User` and `Pet`. They have a many to many relationship, because a User can have many pets, but a pet can belong to more users.

But I want a list of pets, which a specific user is not having.

How is that possible?

EDIT
The above is just an example, so not related to my current task. Just more simple to explain with users and pets. But to specify:

```
PETS TABLE:
ID TYPE
1  Dog
2  Cat
3  Rabit
4  Horse
5  Rat
6  Bat
7  Bird

USERS TABLE:
ID NAME
1  Martin
2  Peter
3  Viggo

PET_USER TABLE:
ID PET USER
1  1   1
2  3   1
3  5   1
```

Then Martin has a dog, a rabbit and a rat.

But I want a list of pets, that he does not have:
Cat, horse, bat and bird

Comment: How's your `pets` table look like?

Comment: Can you give an example of the list of pets that a specific user is not having.

Answer (score 14):

You may try this (your question sounds a little confusing to me tho):

```
$pets = Pet::with('users')->whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('users.id', $id);
})->get();
```

Also, try this as well (if you want):

```
$pets = Pet::with('users')->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($id) {
  $query->where('users.id', '!=', $id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function from laravel to run this out of the box.

You have to join this manually:

```
$pets = Pet::leftJoin('pet_user', function($join) use ($userId){
        $join->on('pets.id', '=', 'pet_user.pet_id');
        $join->on('pet_user.user_id', '=', \DB::raw("'".$userId."'"));
    })->whereNull('pet_user.pet_id')->get();
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work on my case. The idea is to show only those that are not it the pivot table but I see all the table records

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest this method if you already defined ManyToMany relationship on your models :

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$pets = new Pet;
$exception = $user->profile->pluck('id')->toArray();
$pets = $pets->whereNotIn('id',$exception)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> My Solution: worked for me atleast.

Just use :

```
Pet::whereDoesntHave('user');
```

or

```
Pet::whereDoesntHave('user', function($qu) {
   // ...(extended query filter logic)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this query should work for your purpose:

```
$user = User::find(1); // Get the customer with the ID of 1
$this->pets = Pet::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query) use 
($user) {
            $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
        })->get();
```

Comment: What is change in your answer